# How to select nth next data element starting from current?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML structure like so:

```
<div data-month="january"></div>
<div data-month="february"></div>
<div data-month="march"></div>
<div data-month="april"></div>
```

But then there is a lot of HTML structure around the divs.

Now, I know how to select a data month, e.g.: `$('[data-month=february])` gets the jQuery object with the div with the data-month of february.

Now, imagine that I currently have selected this february div like above, is there a way to get the nth neighbour of 'february' (the div n-positions to the right)?

I tried using the [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function, but this cannot start from a current object. (I really need to start from a specific data-month and don't know the index upfront.)

Comment: Have you tried `next()`?

Comment: I created a demo below utilizing the nth-child selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple!
use .next() twice like so:

```
$("[data-month='february']").next().next()
```

more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

A more general approach is to use `index()` to find the current item's index, add an offset to that and then use `parent().children().eq()` like so:

```
var current = $("[data-month='february']");
var other = current.parent().children().eq(current.index() + offset);
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks but I don't think it is very clean to call next() as many times as the index.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers - I added a general approach as well.

Comment: `parent().eq()` doesn't make any sense...an element only ever has one parent

Comment: @charlietfl - The eq() operates after the parent() has finished. It's a traversal method being processed 1 step at a time.

Comment: that's not how it works, each step of chain returns a collection...and `parent()` will be collection of one when original collection preceding was only one element. I think you wanted `parent().children().eq()`

Comment: @charlietfl - That's exactly what is intended. Step from the original item to its (single...) parent, and then to a new child of that parent (again, just a single child)

Comment: but you won't get that without moving to the children , `parent().eq(1)` for example won't return a match. Try it in a demo

Answer (score 1):

Updated

Try utilizing [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) , [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) , [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index)

```js
var current = $("[data-month=february]"), collection = "[data-month]";
var selected = current.siblings(collection).filter(function(i, el) {
   return $(el).index(collection) === current.index(collection) + 2
});

current.add(selected).css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-month="january">january</div>
<div data-month="february">february</div>
<div data-month="march">march</div>
<div data-month="april">april</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not know upfront that I want the `april` element. I only know how many data-months I want to go to the right. The question was not clear on this and I updated it.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers See updated post. Added selector to specify collection selecting from index of.

Answer (score 1):

I created an interactive demo for utilizing nth-child [xengravity.com/demo/nth-child/](http://xengravity.com/demo/nth-child/).

Using nth-child I created the following snippet that should work for your situation:

```js
function UpdateMonthSelection(numberOfMonths){
 var index = $("[data-month='february']").index();
 var newIndex = index + numberOfMonths + 1; //added +1 because nth-child counts from 1 and not 0.

 $("[data-month='february']").css('background','red');
 $("[data-month]:nth-child(" + newIndex + ")").css('background','yellow');
}

//Code specific to dropdown selection
$('select').on('change',function(){
  var selection = $(this).val();
  selection = Number(selection);

  UpdateMonthSelection(selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Select 
<select>
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
Months After Febuary 

<p>
  <div data-month="january">january</div>
  <div data-month="february">february</div>
  <div data-month="march">march</div>
  <div data-month="april">april</div>
  <div data-month="may">may</div>
  <div data-month="june">june</div>
</p>
```

You want to change the value of the "select" drop down to how many months forward you want to select beyond the current selection.